# Dirichlet-convolution

Tags: dirichlet-series, dirichlet-convolution

[image]

[image]

Above is the definition i got from my note.

I was trying to do these and i get stuck when i complete setting up the definition. I am trying to break down $c(n) = ((e_1 - 2e_2) * u)n$

= $( u * e_1 - u * 2e_2)(n)$

Are there any way that i can keep doing that question?

And for the second bit,

I have tried but i can't really figure out how does the $ \frac{1}{1-2^{(1－s)}}$ come out

anyone can give me some help?

Thanks

Comment: We don't have your notes. Please at least define the relevant objects for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

A more conventional notation for those $e_j$ would be $\delta_{j}$ - the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Now, those convolutions. What does convolution with $e_j$ do?
$$(e_j*p)(n) =\sum_{d|n}e_j(d)\cdot p(n/d) = \begin{cases}p(n/j)& j|n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
We space out the entries so they're at distance $j$ instead of $1$, filling in between them with zeros. Note that $e_1$ acts as the identity here; $e_1*p = p$ for all $p$.

What about the Dirichlet series> Well, if $f(s) = \sum_n p(n)n^{-s}$ and $g(s)=\sum_n(e_j*p)(n)n^{-s}$, we get
$$g(s) = \sum_n(e_j*p)(n)n^{-s} = \sum_{j|n} p(n/j)n^{-s} = \sum_k p(k)(jk)^{-s}=j^{-s}\sum_k p(k)k^{-s}= j^{-s}f(s)$$

So then, the specific problem. You have a particular $u$ - which you still haven't defined, but I know what it is from context - so then we get
$$(e_1*u)(n)-2(e_2*u)(n) = \begin{cases}u(n)-2u(n/2)& n\text{ is even}\\ u(n)& n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$
Can you evaluate this? Can you then take the series and get the formula relating the zeta function and the series for these coefficients?